# I have error:Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 32,on line 34,on line 36,on line 38

Tags: php, mysql

```
preg_match('|phpVersion = (.*)\n|',$wampConfFileContents,$result);
$phpVersion = str_replace('"','',$result[1]);
preg_match('|apacheVersion = (.*)\n|',$wampConfFileContents,$result);
$apacheVersion = str_replace('"','',$result[1]);
preg_match('|mysqlVersion = (.*)\n|',$wampConfFileContents,$result);
$mysqlVersion = str_replace('"','',$result[1]);
preg_match('|wampserverVersion = (.*)\n|',$wampConfFileContents,$result);
$wampserverVersion = str_replace('"','',$result[1]);
```

From line 31 to line 38, when i open localhost so it will give this error and localhost's color is still yellow. How can I get it green?

Comment: it means `$result[1]`  doesn't exist (index 1). check by `print_r($result);` and see you have index 1 there or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: print_r($result); now it is working thank u so much @AlivetoDie

Comment: @Dynamo  what is working?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the space in the config-file.
I guess when you select another version of Apache, PHP or MySQL in the WAMP-server menu, it changes the config file but removes the space right after the equal sign:
mysqlVersion ="5.7.4" should be:
mysqlVersion = "5.7.4"